# Is it possible to do identity insert/update in SubSonic 2.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, subsonic-active-record, subsonic2.0

Unfortunately I'm stuck using this basically undocumented/obsolete library (SubSonic 2.0).  I'm trying to do a simple identity insert but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the psuedo-code version of what I'm trying to do:

```
SubSonicExampleObject o = new Select()
                          .From(SubSonicExampleObject.Schema)
                          .Where(SubSonicExampleObject.IdColumn)
                          .IsEqualTo(124124)
                          .ExecuteSingle<SubSonicExampleObject>();

if(o == null)
{
    o = new SubSonicExampleObject();
    o.Id = 124124;
    o.Save();
}
```

I've also tried adding this code above and below this statement, to no success:

```
new InlineQuery()
    .Execute("SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + SubSonicExampleObject.Schema + " ON");

    [CODE ABOVE]

new InlineQuery()
    .Execute("SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + SubSonicExampleObject.Schema + " OFF");
```

Regardless of what I do, SubSonic seems to be ignoring the ID value, and setting it based on the next identity value.

If anyone knows how to do this, I'd be super duper happy!

Comment: Why do you need to insert that specific ID when using an identity column? Could you not write a SQL script in insert this (missing but expected?) record if this is an edge case and then let it use the next identity value for subsequent inserts?

Comment: Hey BateTech, in truth this is for an import application, and there are hundreds of objects inserted this way in a loop.  I ended up doing a large InlineQuery, which includes both the insert statement and toggling the IDENTITY_INSERT (for some reason, running it as three separate inline queries similar to my second example, doesn't work?).  I might post that as the answer if I can't find a cleaner solution :/

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.